# Doctrine DBAL and Oracle keywords

Tags: php, oracle, doctrine-orm, dbal

I'm using DBAL as standalone without ORM because I don't need it. However I have now some problems using oracle keywords in query. 
For instance I have the following code:

```php
$journal = array(
    'LGM_ID'        => 'SEQ_JOURNAL.NEXTVAL',
    'LGM_USER_LOGIN'    => "a user",
    'LGM_DATE'      => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
);
$db->insert('JOURNAL', $journal);
```

And this does not work, I get the following error:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

I assume it's because of usage of sequence. After replacing the first item in the array with an integer, I have the following error:

```
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

This time I think it's because of the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP keyword.

I think at then end when passing the query keywords are converted to string and it does not work. Is there any way to use sequence or other keywords without using extra-things like ORM?

For sequence I think I can run another request before to get the nextval. 
However, for CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, I don't really want to use a php Datetime since my dates are time-zoned and it will add too much extra code for a function handled perfectly by oracle.

The last solution I had is to write the full query as a string and use $db->query(...) but it's not the goal of an abstraction layer.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Can you log the SQL statement that `$db->insert('JOURNAL', $journal);` is sending to Oracle?

Comment: Hi,I'm very new to DBAL so I don't know how to do this easily. I'll check the documentation and come back to you asap.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` behaves, but what I'm certain of is that the sequence's string produces an error.

Doctrine (or PDO for what it's worth) will simply bind the string `SEQ_JOURNAL.NEXTVAL` to the `LGM_ID` column.

As far as I know, you have two ways to handle this issue.

**First method**

Increment the value of the sequence first and get it:

```
$id = (int) $db->fetchColumn('SELECT SEQ_JOURNAL.NEXTVAL FROM dual');
```

Use the retrieved ID in your insert statement:

```
$journal = array(
    'LGM_ID' => $id,
    'LGM_USER_LOGIN' => "a user",
    'LGM_DATE' => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
);

$db->insert('JOURNAL', $journal);
```

The downside of this method is that it involves two queries.

**Second method**

This one is based on a prepared statement, and not a DBAL's shortcut (insert() is a DBAL's shortcut to a real prepared statement, executeUpdate()):

```
$db->executeUpdate("
    INSERT INTO JOURNAL (
        LGM_ID,
        LGM_USER_LOGIN,
        LGM_DATE
    ) VALUES (
        SEQ_JOURNAL.NEXTVAL,
        :userLogin,
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    )
", array(
    :userLogin => 'a user',
));
```

In my opinion it's better than the first one, and you can use the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP function (which I'm not sure about the first use case).

If you want to handle the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP differently you can set the default value of the column to the current date.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering the last comment since I can't format a new comment as I want.

All that I can log with DBAL is this: the request and the parameters:

```
INSERT INTO JOURNAL (LGM_TYPE, LGM_SUBTYPE, LGM_OBJECT_ID, LGM_OBJECT_TABLE, LGM_DATA, LGM_ID, LGM_USER_LOGIN, LGM_DATE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  

Array  
(  
    [0] => 3  
    [1] => 0  
    [2] => 245  
    [3] => ENTITY  
    [4] => Deletion of specific entity  
    [5] => 1  
    [6] => user  
    [7] => CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  
)
```

I'm not sure we can get the exact query as a string.